# NHibernate JoinQueryOver TransformUsing creates cartesian

Tags: nhibernate

In my NHibernate mappings:

(1) 'Individual' contains collections of Names, Addresses, Phones and Enrolments.
(2) 'Enrolments' contains collections of CourseOfferings, Statuses and Flags.

The following returns results with multiple results (Cartesian) for Enrolments and Flags. The top level (i.e. Individual) is distinct though.

```
            var query = session.QueryOver<Individual>()
            .Left.JoinAlias(i => i.Names, () => name)
            .Left.JoinAlias(i => i.Addresses, () => address)
            .Left.JoinAlias(i => i.Phones, () => phone)
            .Where(i => name.ToDate == null)
            .Where(i => phone.ToDate == null)
            .Where(i => address.ToDate == null)
            .Where(i=>i.ContactId ==748)
            .OrderBy(Projections.Property(() => name.NameOther)).Asc
             .Left.JoinQueryOver(i => i.Enrolments, () => enrolment)
            .Left.JoinAlias(s => s.Statuses, () => status)
            .Left.JoinAlias(s => s.CourseOffering, () => courseOffering)
            .Left.JoinAlias(s => s.Flags, () => flag)
            .Where(s => status.ToDate == null)
            .Where(s => flag.ToDate == null)
            //.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<StudentEnrolment>())
             .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Dharmesh

Comment: I think this is a known bug/issue with `DistinctRootEntity` and joining multiple relationships deep. I'll try to find something official

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew. I am desparately waiting for some solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's not ideal, but you could get it to work using a projection on id and a subquery:

```
var subQuery = QueryOver.Of<Individual>()
            ... add all your restrictions ...
            .Select(i => i.Id);

var results = session.QueryOver<Individual>()
              .WithSubquery.WhereProperty(i => i.Id).In(subQuery)
              .List();
```

Results should then contain the list of entities with the correct collections (lazy loaded unless you specify otherwise)

Comment: Probably because of the OrderBy clause - if the list isn't very big you could always order it using Linq after retrieving from the db

Comment: The error says "The query cannot be executed". So the generated SQL is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Future<> queries. Thanks everyone for your help.